# Multiple JOIN with multiple OR very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, join, conditional-statements

I'm currently writing a query which works well, but is terribly slow. I don't really know how I could further speed it up. I don't see any indexes I could set, or any way to change the query to speed it up without breaking it.

About the data structure: I have objects, which can belong to a room, to an apartment or to a floor. a room always belongs to an apartment, and an apartment always belongs to a floor. Sounds complicated but really isn't, this is the hierarchy:

1. Building (this is what I actually have to get for this query)
2. Floor
3. Apartment
4. Room
5. Object (can belong to any 2, 3 or 4)

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT
  whatever
FROM Object AS o
LEFT JOIN Room AS r AS r.id = o.Room_id
LEFT JOIN Apartment AS a
  ON a.id = o.Apartment_id
  OR a.id = r.Apartment_id
LEFT JOIN Floor AS f
  ON f.id = o.Floor_id
  OR f.id = r.Floor_id
  OR f.id = a.Floor_id
JOIN Building AS b ON b.id = f.Building_id
/* some conditions concerning the Building */
```

This query takes about 17 seconds. Acceptable would be < .2s , so its way, way to slow.

Comment: Post some sample data please

Comment: FIrstly, you have several expensive outer joins. Secondly, you have OR's on each join, which is probably not helping. Also, you should run an explain plan on the query, you may be missing some indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data and expected output I cannot say for sure but the following should suffice depending on your data.

```
SELECT *
FROM Building b
INNER JOIN Floor f ON b.id = f.Building_id
INNER JOIN Apartment a ON f.id = a.Floor_id
INNER JOIN Room r ON a.id = r.Apartment_id
INNER JOIN Object o ON r.id = o.Room_id
```

Comment: this will only get me the objects which belong directly to a room

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the query as below.  Nest the query building to room as the natural hierarchy.  At each location where an "object" could be at a floor, apartment or room, do a left-join on that particular condition.  Then, your field list can explicitly reference the different aliases to show it at the floor, apartment or room respectively.

Not knowing your indexes, I would suggest the following

```
table      index
building   (id)  -- assume already since it would be PK
floor      (building_id, id)
apartment  (floor_id, id)
room       (apartment_id, id)
```

object table, have 3 individual indexes on the respect ID it could exist

```
object     (floor_id)
object     (apartment_id)
object     (room_id)

SELECT
      b.id as BuildingID,
      f.id as FloorID,
      COALESCE( FObj.ObjectDescrip, " " ) as FloorObject,
      a.id as ApartmentID,
      COALESCE( AObj.ObjectDescrip, " " ) as ApartmentObject,
      r.id as RoomID,
      COALESCE( RObj.ObjectDescrip, " " ) as RoomObject
   from 
      Building b
         join floor f
            ON b.id = f.building_id
            left join object as FObj
               ON f.id = FObj.floor_id
            left join apartment a
               ON f.id = a.floor_id
               left join object as AObj
                  ON a.id = AObj.apartment_id
               left join room r
                  ON a.id = r.apartment_id
                  left join object as RObj
                     ON r.id = RObj.room_id
```

Since you appeared to be concerned about getting every building, floor, apartment and room for completeness purposes, this SHOULD work for you regardless of an actual object being in any one of the possible locations.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this performs better.

```
SELECT 
    b.id as Building_id,
    f.id as Floar_id,
    a.id as Apartment_id,
    r.id as Room_id,
    COALESE (ro.Description, ao.Description, fo.Description) as Object_Description
FROM Building b
INNER JOIN Floor f ON b.id = f.Building_id
INNER JOIN Apartment a ON f.id = a.Floor_id
INNER JOIN Room r ON a.id = r.Apartment_id
LEFT JOIN Object ro ON r.id = ro.Room_id
LEFT JOIN Object ao on a.id = ao.Apartment_id
LEFT JOIN Object fo on f.id = fo.Floar_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a moron for not coming up with this solution from the start. A simple IF statement in the ON clause for the join to the apartment did the trick for me:

```
SELECT
  whatever
FROM Object AS o
LEFT JOIN Room AS r ON r.id = o.Room_id
LEFT JOIN Apartment AS a
  /* This solved it */
  ON a.id = IF(o.Apartment_id IS NULL, r.Apartment_id, o.Apartment_id)
LEFT JOIN Floor AS f
  ON f.id = o.Floor_id
  OR f.id = r.Floor_id
  OR f.id = a.Floor_id
JOIN Building AS b ON b.id = f.Building_id
/* some conditions concerning the Building */
```

Thanks for all your answers!